# There is a bug in this object extender using hasOwnProperty, I'm uncertain what that bug is or where this extender

Tags: javascript, for-loop, hasownproperty

The following code is supposed to extend foo with bar, the assignment was to find the "bug" in this snippet but for the life of my I can't seem to find the bug. Is there something I'm missing? Some major case where this code would break when extending objects with other objects?

```
var foo = {a:1,b:"2",c:[3]}, bar = {d:"3",e:4,f:5.0};

var extend = function (obj, extension) {
    if (typeof obj === "object" && typeof extension === "object") {
        for (var i in extension) {
            if (extension.hasOwnProperty(i) && !obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
               obj[i] = extension[i];
            }
        }
        return obj;
    }
}
var foo_bar = extend(foo,bar);
console.log(foo_bar); //this logs as expected
```

Comment: The function doesn't return anything nor does it trigger any error if you're passing in non-objects...?!

Comment: @deceze—it returns *undefined*, which seems reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's when you have repeated keys in both objects. Isn't the extending object able to override the extended object's properties?

```
var foo = {a:1,b:"2",c:[3]}, bar = {c:"3",d:4,e:5.0};
var foo_bar = extend(foo,bar); //will result in {a:1,b:"2",c:"3",d:4,e:5.0};
```

Comment: That depends entirely on the definition of what that function is supposed to do...

Comment: You are correct @deceze i was just wondering (that's why i said 'Maybe'). Just trying to help =] (I did tried to just write a comment, but I just started contributing to SO, need more reputation to do that...)

Comment: No, because of: `extension.hasOwnProperty(i) && !obj.hasOwnProperty(i)` so if *obj* already has a particular own property, it will not be replaced by a same–named property of *extension*.